# how to put clickable image jframe

Tags: java

i want to add icons in jframe which does some action while click like buttons.

Comment: Umm, your question doesn't make a ton of sense. Do you want to display some icons to the JFrame itself (like in the top corner), or badge it like on the dock? Or did you want to actually draw images on a panel or label *inside* the JFrame? Also, if you have some code that shows you've already tried something, you'll get a lot more traction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably want to create a JLabel with an Icon and add a MouseListener to the JLabel, like so:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Foo {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    // Create a "clickable" image icon.
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("path/to/image.jpg");
    JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
    label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
        System.out.println("CLICKED");
      }
    });

    // Add it to a frame.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Window");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(label);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a JButton which takes an icon as a parameter and displays it.
[JButton](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html)

I highly suggest trying that out first. Hopefully that will help